# Scenario manager: can you create scenarios in a table, and get the Scenario Manager to read from there?

Tags: excel

Microsoft's official site has an [explanation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/switch-between-various-sets-of-values-by-using-scenarios-2068afb1-ecdf-4956-9822-19ec479f55a2) on how to use scenarios in Excel.

If you name the input cells, the scenario manager will show the name, so it's easier to remember that $C$5 is, say, the price.

My question is: **is it possible to set up the scenarios in a table somewhere in Excel, and get the scenario manager to read from there? Setting multiple scenarios in the scenario manager is very fiddly, time-consuming and error-prone,** especially when the inputs are linked - e.g. setting 10 scenarios where each scenario is an x% change from the previous.

Any suggestions?

PS I know all these things can be done very easily in a scripting language like Python or R, but in this very specific case the calculations are not too complex and the file needs to be shared with other people, so I must use Excel.

VBA would be a last resort because some of these people have VBA disabled by default.

### Edit

To clarify, **what I'd need is a way to create a table like this below**, where those in blue are the inputs, and those in grey are the outputs. I have put together a banal example below, along the lines of the example in the VBA macro answer given below, but the general idea is:

- define a number of scenario as the combination of multiple inputs (more than 2) ;
- create  a table showing, for each scenario, the inputs and some key outputs;
- note the table doesn't have all the possible combinations of all the inputs, like the macro given in one of the examples - that would be too much and wouldn't be very readable.

I could put together a quick VBA script that changes the inputs in the model, reads the result and creates the table, but I was wondering if there is a better way - VBA is typically not very robust, in the sense that just changing the location of one cell can often mess things up. I usually avoid Excel for the more complex models (this would be banal in any scripting language), but this I have to do in Excel.

EDIT #2: 
Trying to further clarify what I have in mind, I have put together the screenshot below. Each output is the result of many different calculations, and CANNOT be calculated as a small, simple formula - if it could, I would not have any issue, of course!

My issue is that:
- if I change an input, then all the many many calculations occurring behind the scenes change
- the outputs are read from all those calculations
 - I cannot use two-way what-if tables

If even this is not clear, the only other thing I can try is to upload an Excel file, which is generally discouraged on SO.

[image]

Comment: Is there a dire need to use the scenario's, as it seems like more of a burden then a gain reading your description. What exactly are you trying to do? Can you not simply take out the scenario editor and do it by hand?

Comment: Could you please show a sample scenario, how many changing cells do you need? Need this information to provide a suitable solution.

Comment: Don't know why the downvote either. As regards the sample provided, it's just a table that if you fill it with formulas then you have the results for the five scenarios.

Comment: @eem I am not following. In the simplest cases where each output can be calculated as a simple formula, yes. But what I have in mind are more complex cases with, say, 2 to 3 tabs of calculations. If I change input1, all the calculations will change accordingly. I cannot use a two-way what-if sensitivity table, either. What I am trying to say is that, despite the example above, my outputs are not as simple as summing or multiplying  the inputs. My outputs are the results of multiple calculations.

Comment: If you want some help, then you should show what kind of inputs you have and what outputs are you looking for, clarify your ideas and put something that someone can work with, show some effort and present what you have done, where are you having problems. So far you started with a question about if something is possible to do, then after you were provided with a method to do it, you move to a list of requirements, so your question looks more and more like a PO; therefore I might not be interested in it anymore.

Comment: @eem I have added another clarification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191457/discussion-between-eem-and-pythonista-anonymous).

Comment: some complicated function, can be easily programmed as an UDF if you ask me. Then there would be no need for any scenario manager. I still wonder why you are so keen on using it, as you obviously dislike it?

Comment: No, UDF is not an option. There are many intermediate steps. I realise I am not explaining myself and I should probably create another question from scratch. I'd delete this but I'm not sure I can since there is already an answer. I have no preference for Scenario Manager: any way to do it in Excel would do. A scripting language like Python or R would be much better for this, but unfortunately they are not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Manager is a built in function with it's own GUI.

For this reason, the function will be limited in what it can call (only data entered in the GUI)

VBA will allow you to manipulate this data, telling it where to pull the changing values and what data to change it by

So the answer for your specific query:

> Can I use Excel without VBA to perform Scenario Manager tasks not set by the GUI?

No.

But it doesn't mean fiddling with the Manger itself would be horrendous. There are ways to teach and learn with it, but also if you save a macro enabled document, users should be able to turn the macro on with the click of a button - so VBA can be an option too

I hope this helps?

Comment: So you mean that I could have my scenario inputs in a separate table and "import" them into scenario manager with VBA? Would you have an example by any chance?